# Entity Framework Migrations on release with Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, ms-release-management

I'm trying to use Visual Studio Team Services to build / release my MVC apps to Azure.

I've been following the [tutorials here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/release/examples/examples-index)

Currently I can push my changes to the repository, which then triggers a build I can then manually select a build for release, customise the web.config file with the settings in the release definition and push the site to the required slot on an Azure Web App.

Now, my problem is with the database. When publishing direct from Visual Studio there is an option to run the code first migrations. Which creates/alters tables and then runs the seed method. Which is great if you are just deploying the site to one web app, but not if you are deploying it multiple times to different instances, hence wanting to use VS Team Services.

I see there are options to run bacpac or sql files in the release definition but I guess that would require creating these files manually for each build.

I'm sure I am missing something. How do others include model/database changes in builds/releases.

It would be nice if someone could just tell me how I should be doing this as Microsoft documentation seems to be lacking in this area.

Comment: Rather than use code first migrations I prefer the declarative route using [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686(v=vs.103).aspx). I have a blog post which explains how I converted the [Contoso University](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) sample app to SSDT [here](http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-with-tfs-our-sample-application).

Comment: Thanks @GrahamSmith I'll look into that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to enable database migrations by adding the following code:

In your Startup.cs file, in the Configuration method, add the following line at the beginning:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DefaultContext, Configuration>());
```

In addition, in your Migrations/Configuration.cs file, make sure the following lines are added to your Configuration method:

```
AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true; //either way works
```

Using these options has allowed me to have my DB migrations run in the past.

Another alternative, depending on what version of MVC you are running, is to set a web.config value and manually run the migrations that way. I had an older project where I put this code into the Global.asax.cs file in the Application Start:

```
        if (bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion"]))
        {
            // Migrations to update the database.
            Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
            var configuration = new Configuration();
            var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);

            migrator.Update();

            Log.Debug("Database migrations complete.");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Dillie-O that's is exactly the kind of solution I was looking for. I'll give it a test when I get chance.

Comment: This works for my but the Seed method was not executed. Any idea how to perform that?

Comment: @WouterJanssens - You would need to do some additional manual work. Potentially do a quick query against your DB after migration to see if data exists in a table you expected to be seeded. If not, then run the seed script.